# TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, matplotlib, opencv

Tengo un problema con el siguiente código:

```
import cv2 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img1 = cv2.imread('images\colombia_city.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('images\colombia_city_2.jpg')

#img = img1 + img2
#img = cv2.add(img1,img2)
abc = cv2.addWeighted(img1,0.7,img2,0.3,55)

plt.imshow(abc)
plt.show()
plt.title("Weighted"); plt.axes()
plt.waitforbuttonpress()
```

Segun **Visual Studio** el problema esta en

> plt.imshow(abc)

Pero cuando pruebo el programa en otro IDE, esto se ejecuta normalmente

Answer (score 2):

La primera posibilidad en la que hay que pensar en estos casos por ser la más simple y común es que no se esté pasando una ruta correcta a `cv2.imread`.

Curiosamente si `cv2.imread` no recibe una ruta correcta no se molesta en lanzar una excepción o un mísero aviso, simplemente retorna `None`. En este caso se usan dos imágenes, si solo una de las rutas fuera incorrecta el código si lanzaría una excepción, pero en `abc = cv2.addWeighted(img1,0.7,img2,0.3,55)` porque se encuentra con un array por un lado y `None` por el otro y eso si que no le parece bien y nos dice algo como:

> The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function cv::arithm_op

Pero si ambas rutas son erróneas `cv2.addWeighted` no falla, se limita a retornar otro `None`. Aquí es cuando a `plt.imshow` le llega un objeto `None` y como **espera una array de floats** lanza la excepción mostrada:

> TypeError: Image data can not convert to float

Para descartar esta posibilidad podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
import cv2 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img1 = cv2.imread(r"images\colombia_city.jpg")
img2 = cv2.imread(r"images\colombia_city.jpg")

assert(img1 is not None), "img1 no existe, compruebe la ruta"
assert(img2 is not None), "img2 no existe, compruebe la ruta"


abc = cv2.addWeighted(img1,0.7,img2,0.3,55)

plt.imshow(img1)
plt.title("Weighted")
plt.axes()
plt.show()
```

> **Nota:** cuando se pasan rutas no se debe utilizar `\` como separador de directorios. La barra inversa (`\`) indica una secuencia de escape, lo cual implica que, por ejemplo, en `"imagenes\nueva.jpg"` el conjunto `\n` sea tomado como un salto de línea. En su lugar se deben usar cadenas crudas (`r"imagenes\nueva.jpg"`), escapar la barra inversa (`"imagenes\\nueva.jpg"`) o utilizar el estilo Unix-like `"imagenes/nueva.jpg"`